# Подскажите как найти элемент в многомерном массиве используя array_search

Tags: php, массивы

есть некий массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [node] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17874292930344481
                    [text] => 
                    [created_at] => 1555015118
                    [did_report_as_spam] => 
                    [owner] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6773204196
                            [is_verified] => 
                            [profile_pic_url] => 
                            [username] => gadalka_lida999
                        )

                    [viewer_has_liked] => 
                    [edge_liked_by] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [node] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 18036829474119034
                    [text] => Her account please
                    [created_at] => 1555019066
                    [did_report_as_spam] => 
                    [owner] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4245266739
                            [is_verified] => 
                            [profile_pic_url] => 
                            [username] => el94__
                        )

                    [viewer_has_liked] => 
                    [edge_liked_by] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 0
                        )

                )

        )
```

как проверить есть ли в этом массиве username = gadalka_lida999

делал так но не работает (

```
$key = array_search("gadalka_lida999", array_column($array, 'username'));
echo $arr[$key]["username"];
```

Answer (score 0):

> *как проверить есть ли в этом массиве username = gadalka_lida999*

```
// $arr - ваш массив

$need = '';
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($i, $k, $data)use(&$need){
    $data !== $i ?: $need = $i;
}, 'gadalka_lida999');

echo $need; // gadalka_lida999
```

---

Или если нужно получить ассоциативный массив:

```
$need = [];
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($i, $k, $data)use(&$need){
    $data !== $i ?: $need[$k] = $i;
}, 'gadalka_lida999');

echo $need['username']; // gadalka_lida999
```

Comment: спасибо то что нужно!

Comment: @Egor если мой ответ является решением вашего вопроса, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 0):

вытащите из массива нужное поле

```
$users = array_map(function($v){
                 return $v['node']['owner']['username'];
             }, $data);
```

и проверьте, что требуется

```
$exists = in_array('username', $users);
```